# Redirect Wordpress index.php

Tags: wordpress

I would like to redirect the `index.php` to another file in my theme directory, but I get an error. `about.php` exists in the theme root directory, but it's not a page template, so there is no reference to it in the database.

**index.php**

```
<?php

wp_redirect(get_site_url()."/about.php");
exit;

?>
```

**Error**

```
This page isn’t working
localhost redirected you too many times.
Try clearing your cookies.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: do you have a page 'about'?

Comment: @Moishy As I've written, the `about.php` file exists in the theme root directory, but it's not a page template.

Comment: why not include it in your index.php

Comment: @Moishy The costumer wants nice URLs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I have found a solution using these guides:**

- https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/
- https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/271878/how-to-properly-insert-a-link-to-a-template-in-wordpress

**For anyone, who faces the same problem, just follow these steps:**

1. Create a single use page template with the `page-` prefix in the theme root directory. (e.g. `page-about.php`)

   - If you put `<?php /* Template Name: About */ ?>` to the top of the template file, it will be available for editors on the "New Page" interface as a page type. If you want to avoid that, just don't use this line.
2. On the "New Page" interface, create a new page with the slug you prefixed with `page-` in the file name. (e.g. `about`)
3. After these steps, Wordpress will know to load your template file, if you link it using the page's slug.

   - You can use the `site_url()` function to create a link. (e.g. `<a href="<?php echo site_url("about"); ?>">About</a>`)
   - Or you can use the `wp_redirect()` function to send the user to the desired page. (e.g. `wp_redirect("about"); exit;`)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this script for redirect to specific standalone test.php page of theme root directory. you need to use get_stylesheet_directory_uri() function because your PHP page exists in theme ROOT directory.

wp_redirect( get_stylesheet_directory_uri()."/test.php" );
exit;

Comment: It loads the file, but makes the theme directory path visible in the URL, which I want to avoid.

Comment: You can use the url-rewriting to avoid the theme directory path.